# javascript change form onsubmit dynamically

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox, checked, onsubmit

I have a form with some action and onsubmit values, which is submitted through a submit input tag. The problem is that it should be submittable by two buttons, so I wrote a function for the second button to change the action and onsubmit values of the form:

```
<a href="javascript:submitCompare()" class="submit">Compare</a>

function submitCompare()
{
    document.myForm.action = "anotherAction.php";
    document.myForm.onsubmit = function() {return countChecked()};
    document.myForm.submit();
}

function countChecked()
{
  var n = $(".reports input:checked").length;
  if (n >= 3 ) {
    alert ('You must select less than 3 reports.');
    return false;
  }
  else return true;
}
```

After clicking on the Compare link it sends me to the anotherAction.php page correctly, but even when I have more than 2 selected checkboxes (which is the validation rule). Can somebody help me make the onsubmit function work correctly?

Comment: Just a side-note, I think `(n > 2)` is enough instead of `(n >= 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `submitCompare()`, you explicitly and unconditionally call

```
 document.myForm.submit();
```

What you probably want instead there is

```
 if (countChecked()) {
   document.myForm.submit();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that way it simplifies the whole idea and actually works!

Answer (score 7):

```
document.myForm.onsubmit = function() {return countChecked()};
```

should be

```
document.myForm.onsubmit = function( e ) {
   e = e || window.event;
   if ( !countChecked() ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.returnValue = false;
   }
};
```

Returning false on a submit will just end any further function execution. You want to preventDefault submission behavior if you don't want it to submit.

Comment: Tried it, but there was no change in the behaviour of the submit process.

Comment: Perhaps it is your countChecked function. try doing some console.log to see if it is getting the right amount of checked checkboxes

Comment: countChecked() returned correct values. I really don't know why your solution didn't work but @Otto Allmendinger got it right for me, so case closed :)

Answer (score 4):

It is a late reply, but if someone else is looking at this...

instead of:

```
document.myForm.onsubmit = function() {return countChecked()};
```

I think you wanted:

```
document.myForm.setAttribute("onsubmit", "return countChecked()");
```

Comment: You saved my valuable last minute time