# Ajax result evaluation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

i have a HTML from, and i want to validate it before it is submited, and i used ajax in the validation, i want it to submit the form if the ajax result is "OK" and to show an alert if else, The result is definatly "OK" but it is not submiting the form, pls help!!

---

here is the HTML code i used

```
 <form action="newplan.php" onsubmit="return validateplan();" method="post">
                      <TABLE style="font-size: small;width: 100%;background:  #7cdafe;">
    <Tr>
    <td>
        Planer Name <input type="text" disabled value="<?=$me['name']?>">
    </TD>
    <td>
        Title
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title this plan">
             </td>
             <tD>
        <LABEL for="month">Month</LABEL>
        <SELECT id="month" name="month">
            <OPTION value="0">Choose</OPTION>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
        </SELECT>

        <LABEL for="week">Week</LABEL>
        <select name="week" id="week">
            <OPTION>Choose</OPTION>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tR>
</TABLE>
<div>
         <LABEL for="subdate">Submition Date</LABEL><input type="text" id="subdate"         name="subdate" value='<?=date("F d,Y")?>'></input>
         <input type="submit" name="go" value="Save">
         <input type="test" id="clar" value="0">
         <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit">
         </div>
         </form>
```

---

And here is the js, i have linked jquery in the head of the page

JS

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateplan(){
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var month = $("#week").val();
        var subdate = $("#subdate").val();
        var week = $("#week").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/plan_validate.php',
            data: {title: title,month: month,subdate: subdate,week: week},
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 'OK'){
                    alert("We are OK so far");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(data);
                }

            },
            error: function(){
               alert("There is something wrong");
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: looks like something got cut off your question by the edit....?

Comment: No, it was cut off before I edited. I think user2338870 is just repeating what was said above the code: "The result is definatly "OK" but it is not submiting the form"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous, so before it is validating at server side, it is returning false. Thats why your form is not submitting.

instead of `<form action="newplan.php" onsubmit="return validateplan();" method="post">`

You can submit the form in ajax success function and else show the alert;
try this :
change your form tag like this and

```
<form action="newplan.php" method="post" id="myform">
```

call the submit in ajax success function

```
$( "#myform" ).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code looks to be doing:

<sub>please clarify if any of these assumptions are incorrect.</sub>

1. User fills out the form, clicks submit.
2. Javascript `validateplan()` function is called.
3. `validateplan()` sends an AJAX request with the form data to `ajax/plan_validate.php`
4. `plan_validate.php` processes the input and checks for errors. Response is returned.
5. Your success function is checking that the data equals the bare string 'OK'.
6. Nothing else is done with your data.

What is `plan_validate.php` supposed to be doing? Just error checking the form? Or actually doing something with the data? You say:

> The result is definatly "OK" but it is not submiting the form.

Are you seeing your `alert("We are OK so far");`? If yes, then you are submitting the form, but only to `plan_validate.php`, not to your form action `newplan.php`. If you are expecting the form to be submitted to `newplan.php`, then you need program it to do that.

Your code in the form tag that says `onsubmit="return validateplan();"` is telling the browser to use the return value of `validateplan()` to decide whether or not to submit to the `action` attribute.

The last line of your `validateplan()` function is `return false;`, thus `validateplan` always returns false and the form is never submitted. When you `return true;` from inside your success function, you are only returning *from that anonymous function*, **not** the `validateplan` function.

If you want to submit the form to `newplan.php` after getting an OK response from `plan_validate.php`, you need to add that in your `success: function` after your OK alert.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368000/javascript-change-form-onsubmit-dynamically) is a reasonable starting point for figuring out how to do the rest of what you need. Since you're already referencing jQuery (at least, that's what I assume your `$` calls are for), you can look at the `[`.on()`][2] and [`.submit()`][3](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) helpers for some shortcuts you can use with jQuery.

**Note:** You probably do not want to change your `validateplan()` to `return true;`, as this would always submit your form to `newplan.php` regardless of the response from `plan_validate.php`. This is because your AJAX is asynchronous and it executes outside of the rest of the flow through `validateplan()`.

**Note 2:** If you were to change your form to have `onsubmit=validateplan()` without the `return` in there, some browsers would ignore the return value of `validateplan` and always submit the form. Just something to be aware of.